# Excel VBA AciveListObject

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that is using excel tables (ListObjects) called "Tables" and it seems I cannot get the name of the object that was just changed. I have an event that will call a Class and I need to set the property of the active listObject.

Is there away that you can do something similar to `ActiveListObject.Name`? I know that you can use `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName")` that isn't going to work being that I have 5 tables on this sheet.

Please reply with any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to the Listobject which contains the active cell, you can use:

```
Dim oList as ListObject
set oList = activecell.Listobject
If not olist is nothing then
' do whatever
End If
```